# Can we have an electrophoresis tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There seem to be around only 15 questions now but I guess they'd steadily increase. Somehow I don't know which tag to fit such questions under

Comment: I'm shrugging about this, and if people need it, then why not $\ldots$ also as a FYI, Biology.SE has a [gel-electrophoresis](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gel-electrophoresis) tag.

Comment: There should be this tag as electrochemistry isn't suitable for this

Answer (score 5):

Although there are currently [only 6 questions mentioning electrophoresis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=electrophoresis+is%3Aquestion), we have tags that are viable and have fewer uses. I am looking at you [iupac](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iupac)!

I have applied it to [What causes the DNA fragments to stop moving in gel electrophoresis?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/519/4945) since you lack the privilege. Please go ahead, apply it to other questions, and write a short tag usage and wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I’m leaning towards *no*. In fact, I think that most of the questions that would ask for an [electrophoresis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrophoresis) tag have either been already asked or are better asked over at [biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com).

Electrophoresis is very much a biological method that many chemists know little about, especially if they are far away from biochemistry/chemical biology. Thus it makes little sense to have such a tag here.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/519/gel-electrophoresis-what-causes-the-dna-fragments-to-stop#comment853_519

Comment: @Martin-マーチン One of the questions subsumed under ‘already been asked’ ;)

Comment: it's not about the question, it's the comment I was linking to